# Loop through list and "return" only if no matches

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to loop through a list of strings and check them against a single string. If nothing is found that matches then we need to exit the code.

```
// loadedObj.Settings contains the list of strings, can be any number of strings     
foreach (var currentCheckBox in loadedObj.Settings.Where(currentCheckBox => currentCheckBox != null))
    {   
        // docTypeAlias is a single string that needs to be matched
        var docTypeAlias = sender.ContentType.Alias;
        // This is the current value of currentCheckBox
        var requiredTypeAlias = currentCheckBox;
        if (!requiredTypeAlias.Equals(docTypeAlias)) return;
    }
```

The code works fine if there is only 1 string in Settings, but as soon as you have multiple strings, if the first one doesn't match obviously the code exits too soon.

Comment: `currentCheckBox` seems to be a CheckBox. How can a CheckBox be a list of strings? Your code also tries nothing that seems to relate to your text. Can you edit to clarify types and what your actual goal is?

Comment: Why not using a regular ׳foreach׳ loop?

Comment: Sorry, that was a name copied from some other code, its actually a list of checkBox items read in from an xml file.

Comment: Then could you edit your question and make it more accurate, so that it's useful to others in the future? If your question is invalid, and someone happens to guess what you're actually looking for and provide an answer you can use, you can still make your question better so others later might benefit. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Any` to see if any element in the sequence matches your criteria. If none do, the result will be false.

```
var docTypeAlias = sender.ContentType.Alias; 
bool hasMatch = loadedObj.Settings.Any(current => docTypeAlias.Equals(current));
if (hasMatch)
{
    // can work
}
else
{
    // can't work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean to record the answer.

```
bool found = false;
foreach (var currentCheckBox in loadedObj.Settings.Where(currentCheckBox => currentCheckBox != null)) 
{    
    // docTypeAlias is a single string that needs to be matched 
    var docTypeAlias = sender.ContentType.Alias; 
    // This is the current value of currentCheckBox 
    var requiredTypeAlias = currentCheckBox; 
    if (requiredTypeAlias.Equals(docTypeAlias)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    } 
}
if (!found) return;
```

Alternatively, make this a separate function:

```
bool ControlIsListed(object sender, MySettingsClass loadedObj)
{
    foreach (var currentCheckBox in loadedObj.Settings.Where(currentCheckBox => currentCheckBox != null)) 
    {    
        // docTypeAlias is a single string that needs to be matched 
        var docTypeAlias = sender.ContentType.Alias; 
        // This is the current value of currentCheckBox 
        var requiredTypeAlias = currentCheckBox; 
        if (requiredTypeAlias.Equals(docTypeAlias)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And call it with:

```
private void eventhandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ControlIsListed(sender, loadedObj)) return;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want "continue" (to skip the rest of the code in foreach and check next item) instead of "return" that returns from the function.

Consider using FirstOrDefault if you just need to check for some predicate on a collection.

Comment: The code looks to me like shortened sample - Ian Houghton should be doing something if "found" case too... but yes for sample as it is there continue is useless. I think sample is translation of JQuery.each where return will essentially do continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool doAnyMatch = loadedObj
                    .Settings
                    .Where(x => x != null)
                    .Any(x => x.Equals(docTypeAlias));

if(!doAnyMatch) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this instead, if I understood it well

```
 loadedObj.Settings.Find(delegate(String currentCheckBox)
{
    return sender.ContentType.Alias == currentCheckBox
});
```

if something is find it will return the `string` if not `null`.